# Prolog - How to make a variable list out of a given list from input file?

Tags: list, variables, prolog

I have a input predicate will read the file as a list: input(Filename,List). The list then will be in the format of

`["_","_","_",9,"_","_"]`

`"_"` is literally the character underscore `"_"` here, not a wild card. The question is how can I write a predicate pred(List,List2) then transform all the `"_"` into variables but keep `9` still at the same position? So If I type in

`input(Filename,List),pred(List,X).`

I will get something like

```
X = [_G1426, _G1429, _G1432, 9, _G1438, _G1441].
```

I know if I define a predicate

`pred(a,[_,_,_,9,_,_]).`

Then by calling `pred(a,X)` I can have the similar result. But the thing is how to make it adaptive to all kinds of input lists, `9` might be at a another position or the list might be of different size. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
to_var_list([],[]).
to_var_list([A|R1],[B|R2]):-
     (A = '_' ->
      true;
      A = B),
    to_var_list(R1,R2).
```

Exchange `'_'` with `"_"` if you actually have one character strings and not underscore atoms.
Also, there is a `read` predicate that does something like you want to achieve, but it expects a `.` after your lists in the file.

Comment: have you checked out `read`? it really does almost exactly what you want.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't modify the input. The input list has no "." at the end.

Comment: if you are using SWI, maybe `term_string` could also help, but it seems to be a newer addition.