# Prolog - Given a list of lists how to assign independent variables to certain members of list

Tags: list, prolog

for a list given like `[[*,.,*],[.,.,.],[*,.,*]]`
how do we assign logical variables to every '.' present in the puzzle?

Do I have to create another list of which contains logical variables to be assigned to the list?

I am trying to solve a word-fill puzzle, where I will take a list of words, a square crossword type grid and return the only solution, A sample crossword grid is as follows,
*.*
...
*.*

where it can be split into rows as,
[[*,.,*],[.,.,.],[*,.,*]]

I would like to make a list with logical variables as,
[[*,X,*],[A,B,C],[*,Z,*]]

so that I can fill the puzzle with a work from the word list as follows,

---

|*C*|
|MAN|
|*T*|

---

The input crossword-grid can be of any size but is always a square.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you did "assign" (aka unify) variables with each `.` you'd just end up with a series of `X = '.'`. What does that give you?

Comment: I am trying to solve a wordfill puzzle, where i can unify words (provided in a list)  with the variables to produce a solution.

Comment: Now that's what you should have put in your question in the first place. Had you done that you may have avoided the down-vote. I gave you an up-vote to balance it out.

Comment: What have you tried till now? There was a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26128338/801553)  a few weeks ago.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. I have a function to unify words with a list of logical variables, which may be created as above,                                 all_member([], _).
all_member([W|Ws], Ss) :-
    member(W, Ss),
    all_member(Ws, Ss).

Comment: what about your input? is it in a file? what you have posted isn't a prolog term.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is of this specific form, simply unify it with a list that has variables in the places of interest and underscores everywhere else will do the trick:

```
demo(L) :-
    L = [[_,A,_],[B,C,D],[_,E,_]|_]
,   write(A), nl, write(B), nl, write(C), nl, write(D), nl, write(E), nl.
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Cu0Kxm)

Comment: Thanks.But is there a way to do this if a list is not in a specific form?, I am trying to solve a puzzle, so the list can be of any size.

Comment: @Hello You can match unused portion of the list after `[_E,_]` with `|_` (see edit).